# How to use a unit-testing framework for a function that has a dynamic output in Racket?

Tags: unit-testing, random, lisp, racket, rackunit

I was doing exercise 3.5 on SICP book.

A Monte Carlo implementation in Racket generates the following code:

```
(define (monte-carlo trials experiment)
  (define (iter trials-remaining trials-passed)
    (cond ((= trials-remaining 0)
           (/ trials-passed trials))
          ((experiment)
           (iter (- trials-remaining 1) (+ trials-passed 1)))
          (else
           (iter (- trials-remaining 1) trials-passed))))
  (iter trials 0))

(define (random-in-range low high)
  (let ((range (- high low)))
    (+ low (random range))))
; questão propriamente dita
(define (estimate-integral predicate x1 x2 y1 y2 trials)
  (*(* (- x1 x2) (- y1 y2))
    (monte-carlo trials predicate)))

(define (circulo?)
  (>= 1 (+ (square (random-in-range -1 1))
           (square (random-in-range -2 1)))))

(define (estimate-pi)
  (estimate-integral circulo? -1.0 1 -2 1 100000))
; Fiquei brincando com os os parametros do retangulo, desde que o circulo continue dentro dele
(define square
  (lambda (x) (* x x)))
```

The code is right.
However, I decided to  insert some unit tests.

Hence, I imported the library rackunit and used the following test:

```
(require rackunit)

(check-equal? (estimate-pi) 3.00906)
```

This is obviously a problem and the tests will always fail since the output is dynamic due to a random function.

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a built-in check for this - the preferred solution:

```
(check-= (estimate-pi) 3.1416 1e-4 "Incorrect value for pi")
```

The previous check verifies that the result falls within an acceptable *tolerance* value (also known as *epsilon*), and it's equivalent to this:

```
(check-true (<= (abs (- (estimate-pi) 3.1416)) 1e-4))
```

The `1e-4` part is the tolerance in scientific notation, it means that if the difference between the actual value and the expected value is less than `0.0001`, then we accept the result as correct. Of course, you can tweak the tolerance value to suit your needs - the smaller the number, the higher the required precision. Also, it's useful to know that if `check-=` didn't exist, we could define our own check, like this:

```
(define-binary-check (check-in-tolerance actual expected tolerance)
  (<= (abs (- actual expected)) tolerance))

(check-in-tolerance (estimate-pi) 3.1416 1e-4)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. But what does 1e-3 mean?

Comment: There's also `check-=`, which is the built-in version of this

Comment: @AlexKnauth thanks! I wasn't aware of that check; I updated my answer.